# Spring Kafka - create streams dynamically

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I need to create kafka streams dynamically from config files, which contain source topic name and configs per each stream .  App need to have tens of kafka streams and streams will be different on each environment (e.g. stage, prod).
Is it possible to do that with `spring-kafka` library?

We can do that easy with `kafka-streams`:

```
@Bean
public List<KafkaStreams> kafkaStreams() {
    return streamRouteProperties.stream()
            .map(routeProperty -> createKafkaStream(routeProperty))
            .collect(toList());
}

private KafkaStreams createKafkaStream(KafkaConfigurationProperties kafkaProperties) {
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<Object, String> stream = builder.stream(kafkaProperties.getTopicName());
    Topology topology = builder.build();
    StreamsConfig streamsConfig = new StreamsConfig(kafkaProperties.getSettings());
    return new KafkaStreams(topology, streamsConfig);
}
```

and we need to implement spring `SmartLifecycle` interface, so all streams will be started and closed automatically.

is it possible to do the same using `spring-kafka`?
as I see, we need to create each kafka stream in code, and I don't see a possibility how to create list of kafka streams using `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`.
for each required stream I need to do the following:

```
@Bean
public KStream<?, ?> kStream(StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder) {
    Consumed<String, String> consumed = ..;
    KStream<String, String> kStream = streamsBuilder.stream(topicName, consumed);
    kStream.process(() -> eventProcessor);
    return kStream;   
}

@Bean
public FactoryBean<StreamsBuilder> streamsBuilder() {
    return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(streamsConfig);
}
```

but how to create list of kafka streams dynamically using `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` just brings some opinionated, convenient API for Spring application context, but that doesn't mean that you always should be tied with that.

Luckily, the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` doesn't have too much value over regular Kafka Streams. Maximum what it does it is a lfecycle control over created internally `KafkaStreams`.

You are feel free just stay with the raw Kafka Streams API and don't over complicate your code with an attempt to make it your requirements based on the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`, which is really designed for one static set of options.

Comment: thank you for explaining in which direction should I go